# Cmake- Could not find the following Boost libraries:boost_thread, boost_system

Tags: qt, cmake, windows-7, cgal, cmake-gui

I want to use CGAL in developing an Application,
I'm using :win7, CGAL 4.10 ,Microsoft visual studio 2013 , CMake 3.9.3 , boost 1.65.1, QT creator 4.2.0 (Qt5.7.1)

while Configuring CGAL using Cmake , it is showing the following error:

```
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.65.1
Boost include path: C:/local/boost_1_65_1

Could not find the following Boost libraries:

      boost_thread
      boost_system

Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
```

[show screenshot of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Cm1.png)

I added BOOST_ROOT manually to environment vairables
 tried many versions of boost ,cmake and cgal with visual sutudio 2015 , 2013 and non of the was working

I appreciate any help.thank you

Comment: Did you compile your Boost first?

Comment: Probably, your Boost libraries are **incompatible** with your compiler; e.g. they could be created for other version of Visual Studio. Set variable *Boost_DEBUG* to *ON* and see (in configuration log) which exact names of libraries are searched. Then compare these with names you have installed.

Comment: @arrowd no, I didn't , how to compile? it and Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, some Boost libraries aren't header-only. Refer to Boost documentation to learn how to compile it. It should be pretty straightforward and then CMake would be able to find libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev where is Boost_DEBUG found?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter for cmake: `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON <other-options>`. As for description, it can be found in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindBoost.html).